# Requesting the next page of results from a web api with AngularJS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsonp, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am using a web api that provides results with paging built for me and I can get the first page of results via the $resource service in a controller as soon as the page loads.  That's working as expected.

How do I page to the next set of results while using the URL in the response meta and hook it into the Twitter Bootstrap paging control?

Here's an idea of the response JSON I get:

```
{
    "results": [
               { "some-data" },
               { "some-data" }
            ],
    "meta": {
              "totalRecords": 33,
              "pageSize":     10,
              "nextSet":      "http://api.domain.com/?action=whatever&pageSize=10&offset=10"
          }
}
```

I've tried to set the next paging control to the URL in the meta while in my callback and for some reason my controller executes the first request to get the data and then tries to execute the request for the next set and it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please provide some coded examples? Thanks. The problem could very well be in the way you defined the Resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work.

```
var WebApi = $resource('http://api.domain.com/');
$scope.action   = 'initial action for first page goes here';
$scope.pageSize = 10;
$scope.offset   = 0;
$scope.loadPage = function() {
    var serverData = WebApi.get( 
        {action: $scope.action, pageSize: $scope.pageSize, offset: $scope.offset}, 
        // calls http://api.domain.com/?action=<action>&pageSize=<pageSize>&offset=<offset>
        function() {
            // page data is in serverData.results
            $scope.model = serverData.results;
            // update $scope properties for next page: action, pageSize, offset
            $scope.action = ...
            ...
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will try that and let you know how it works out for me.

Comment: The code above was very helpful.  I check to see if the nextSet property has a value to determine whether I can move to the next page and then increment my offset when I click next.  That click action then updates the model and in the callback I can check the nextSet again and also update my previous paging button based on the offset count.

My next and previous buttons update the offset and then call to update the model.  All that's left is to calculate the number of pages and plug that into my pagination control via Twitter Bootstrap.  Easy enough.

Thanks again Mark.